# Read csv with "^" + character delimiter with the C engine

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a file that looks as follows:

```
$ head my_file
NVQe2jNT^A1407334383000^A7050
Oo6juv39^A1407334164000^A30
z0mLJub2^A1407334518000^A75
```

The field separator is literally `^A`. If I do:

```
df = pd.read_csv('my_file', sep='\^A')
```

or:

```
df = pd.read_csv('my_file', sep='^A')
```

I get:

```
/Users/josh/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py:624: 
ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not 
support regex separators; you can avoid this warning by specifying engine='python'.
```

Is there any way to use the `C` engine against this file?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there's no way to tell it that your separator isn't a regex (which is a bad API design in my opinion), so you may be out of luck. :/

Comment: What version python, pandas are you using? This works fine for me using pandas 0.14.1 and python 3.3.4 64-bit. Maybe a pyhon 2.7 issue, I only get the same warning as you if I do `pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep='^A')` but `pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep='\^A')` worked fine

Answer (score 0):

df = pd.read_csv('my_file', sep='^A',engine='python')